# Returning the correct path for a wordpress CHILD theme

Tags: wordpress

I know wordpress quite well, but this is the first time that I am creating a child theme. I realized that I need to link everything differently in a child theme.

I got it to work for images by using "stylesheet_directly", like so:

```
  <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/icon.png" />
```

However, I am now trying to enqueue a javascript file in the child theme's functions.php I tried using "stylesheet_directory" again, but it returned a path of the parent's theme, and not the child theme.

Why does "stylesheet_directory" work for the image files in my child theme, but not for enqueing javascript files in my functins file?

Here is what I have in my functions. What else can I use to return the correct path?

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ga-slider', bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/ga-slider.js');
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of yours `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')` . 
  **Ex.**

```
wp_enqueue_script('script-name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'),2, true );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` for relative path to the child theme directory.
`get_stylesheet_directory()` will return absolute path of the child theme directory.

- Docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory

Comment: Thank you. This worked. But now I have a different problem. It is returning the correct path, but the javascript file doesn't seem to work now. If I link the javascript file in the parent theme's header, then my slider works properly, but if I enque it in my child theme's functions file with the code you gave, it returns the correct path now, but my slider doesn't work. Do you have any idea why? Is it a dependency issue? It only requires jquery, nothing else.

Comment: You should enqueue scripts in functions file rather than in the header as mentioned above by @vladja
You can read more on it https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: @Shtarley. Check the page source, about where it is getting loaded